# find function hangs the page during search in Jquery

Tags: jquery, find, pagespeed

I have a contact form within which I am using find() function to search the mandatory fields.

The problem is that within IE, this takes over a minute to run. All other browsers are fine.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Code is:-

```
$("#contact-form").find("input.mandatory, select.mandatory, textarea.mandatory").each(function(i,a){
            var val = $(a).val();
            var name = $(a).attr("name");
            $(a).removeClass("hasError");
            if(!val){
                errors++;
                $(a).addClass("hasError");
            }
            if(name=="email" && !validateemail(val)){
                errors++;
                $(a).addClass("hasError");
            }
            if($(a).is("select") && $(a).hasClass("hasError")){
                $(a).next().find(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("hasError");
            }   
            if ($(a).is("select") && $(a).val()){
                $(a).next().find(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("hasError");
            }
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `$("#contact-form").find(".mandatory").find("input, select, textarea")` any faster? Also, would it be possible just to call `$("#contact-form").find(".mandatory")`?

Comment: mc10, that didnt work. Thanks though.

Comment: $("#contact-form").find(".mandatory") worked. Thanks mc10